# WSHttpBinding and HTTP and Windows Authentication

Tags: wcf, http, authentication, wshttpbinding

I tried to setup WCF service with `WSHttpBinding` and Windows Authentication and HTTP protocol, not HTTPS. Is it possible? I am using IIS 7. Current my config file is below.

With this config application throws exception:

> Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the
>   endpoint with binding WSHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes
>   are [].

My code is:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WsBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WsBehavior" name="LoginService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WsBinding" contract="ILoginService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="http://localhost:50001/Ws/" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="1">
      <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
        <add prefix="http://localhost:50001/Ws/" />
      </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>

    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WsBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got next error

> The authentication schemes configured on the host
>   ('IntegratedWindowsAuthentication') do not allow those configured on
>   the binding 'WSHttpBinding' ('Anonymous').  Please ensure that the
>   SecurityMode is set to Transport or TransportCredentialOnly. 
>   Additionally, this may be resolved by changing the authentication
>   schemes for this application through the IIS management tool, through
>   the ServiceHost.Authentication.AuthenticationSchemes property, in the
>   application configuration file at the 
>   element, by updating the ClientCredentialType property on the binding,
>   or by adjusting the AuthenticationScheme property on the
>   HttpTransportBindingElement.

So answer on my question. It's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register a base address in the host/baseAddresses config node.  Also, your DNS identity should be a host name and not the endpoint address:

```
<services> 
  <service behaviorConfiguration="WsBehavior" name="LoginService">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:50001/Ws"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host> 
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WsBinding" contract="ILoginService"> 
      <identity> 
        <dns value="localhost" /> 
      </identity> 
    </endpoint> 
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" /> 
  </service> 
</services>
```

Comment: thanks for answer. It works for anonymous, but not for Windows Authentication.